# react-native-beacons-manager Not showing any beacons on Android

Tags: android, react-native, ibeacon

Using https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager

Works lovely on iOS, however, on Android, after I begin ranging beacons, the beacon array shows up with nothing in it (there are 6 beacons next to me and they all show up on iOS).

Here's what I'm doing:

```
componentDidMount() {

 // Start detecting all iBeacons in the nearby
Beacons.detectIBeacons();

Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion('Estimotes', 'B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D').then((data)=>{

    console.log(data);

}).catch((reason) => {

    console.log(reason);


});


// Print a log of the detected iBeacons (1 per second)
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('beaconsDidRange', (data) => {

    console.log(data);

});

}
```

In my console, I get this:

```
{beacons: Array(0), uuid: "b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d", identifier: "Estimotes"}
```

I left the UUID of the Estimotes as default so this should work. Using a Samsung Galaxy S8+ for testing. Am I doing anything wrong coding wise here? Are there additional permissions on Android that I am missing? Bluetooth and Location services are on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. Newer versions of android require additional permissions. In your Manifest, throw this guy in there:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

.... if you're using react-native-kontaktio (which is better than react-native-beacons-manager imo) you'll also need to throw this in your Manifest in the  `<application>` section:

```
<service android:name="com.kontakt.sdk.android.ble.service.ProximityService"/>
```

Then in your app.js you'll need to request the permission like () make sure you

```
import PermissionsAndroid
from 'react-native'
```

:

```
componentDidMount() {

    try {
        const granted = PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            {
                'title': 'Location Permission',
                'message': 'Activeev needs to access your location.'
            }
        )
        console.log('here', granted);
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log("Location Permitted")
        } else {
            console.log("Location permission denied")
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }
}
```

Working like a charm now. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Worked like a charm! but import should be like this
`import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native'`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. It definitely worked. Based on your answer, below is my implementation.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, DeviceEventEmitter, ListView , Text} from 'react-native';
import Beacons  from 'react-native-beacons-manager';
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native'


export default class App extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {

    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
              'title': 'Location Permission',
              'message': 'Activeev needs to access your location.'
          }
      )
      console.log('here', granted);

      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log("Location Permitted")
           // Start detecting all iBeacons in the nearby
            Beacons.detectIBeacons();

            Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion('test', '85d37dd8-a9dc-48a8-ab1c-b86fcb7a6a17').then((data)=>{   
                console.log(data);   
            })
            .catch((reason) => {   
                console.log(reason);   
            });

            // Print a log of the detected iBeacons (1 per second)
            DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('beaconsDidRange', (data) => {
              console.log(data);
            });
      } else {
          console.log("Location permission denied")
      }

    }catch (err) {
        console.warn(err)
    }

  }  

 render(){
   return(
     <View></View>
   );
 }

}
```